# Lambdas can't be compared

Tags: c++11

I was wondering if this is Standard, or a bug in my code. I'm trying to compare a pair of my homegrown function objects. I rejected the comparison if the type of function object is not the same, so I know that the two lambdas are the same type. So why can't they be compared?

Comment: When you say "homegrown," do you mean that you explicitly declared a class with operator() in it?  Or did you use the new lambda syntax?

Comment: @templatetypedef: I mean it was my own version of std::function, which is implemented via inheritance and type erasure.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every C++0x lambda object has a distinct type, even if the signature is the same.

```
auto l1=[](){}; // one do-nothing lambda
auto l2=[](){}; // and another
l1=l2; // ERROR: l1 and l2 have distinct types
```

If two C++0x lambdas have the same type, they must therefore have come from the same line of code. Of course, if they capture variables then they won't necessarily be identical, as they may have come from different invocations.

However, a C++0x lambda does not have any comparison operators, so you cannot compare instances to see if they are indeed the same, or just the same type. This makes sense when you think about it: if the captured variables do not have comparison operators then you cannot compare lambdas of that type, since each copy may have different values for the captured variables.

Answer (score 0):

Is the equality operator overloaded for your lambda object?  If not I'm assuming you'll need to implement it.

Comment: The point of the question is that I believed that one should be provided.

Comment: I'd argue that you need to implement a comparison operator.  I believe the problem is that when you inherit the operator needs to be redefined.

Comment: Do you know what lambda's are? @Dead cannot do that because he doesn't implement lambda's, the compiler does.

Comment: But he's comparing his "homegrown" version of them.  I'm asking did he implement a comparison operator for his class he created.

Comment: The question specifies that I'm trying to do it.